# OpenGL Jogl GL4 Fragment Shader Driver Crash

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, nvidia, jogl

this is my fragment Shader for a Raytracing Render. I implemented a port of the bresenhams line drawing algo to check for a hit.

The problem is my graphics card driver crashed upon launch.

A few things i have tried:

- Leave out the Array access to make sure it doesn't have anything to do with index exception etc.
- Use a dummy code that has a calculation intensive for loop to check if it has to do with not being performant enough.
- downgrade from the latest nvidia drivers to 3 different versions.
- Write a while loop that doesn't terminate. (The rendering still gets updated so my guess is that opengl compiler detects things like that?)

I cant see any obvious error so i wonder why the crash happens.

here is the fragment shader. The Method bresenham() seems to cause the crash.

```
#version 430

layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer target
{
    int data[];
};

out vec4 fragColor;
in vec4 gl_FragCoord;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 cameraPos;


vec3 lightColor = vec3(2,2,1.5);
vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1);
vec3 targetColor = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1);

float rad = 5;


int getIndex(vec3 pos){

    int x = int(mod(pos.x,7));
    int y = int(mod(pos.y,7));
    int z = int(mod(pos.z,7));

    return 2;
}


bool bresenham(vec3 origin, vec3 dir){



    int xs;
    int ys;
    int zs;

    float dx = abs(dir.x - origin.x);
    float dy = abs(dir.y - origin.y);
    float dz = abs(dir.z - origin.z);

    if (dir.x > origin.x){
        xs = 1;
    }else{
        xs = -1;
    }
    if (dir.y > origin.y){
        ys = 1;
    }else{
        ys = -1;
    }

    if (dir.z > origin.z){
        zs = 1;
    }else{
        zs = -1;
    }


    if (dx >= dy && dx >= dz){
        float p1 = 2 * dy - dx;
        float p2 = 2 * dz - dx;
        while (origin.x != dir.x){
            origin.x += xs;

            if (p1 >= 0){
                origin.y += ys;
                p1 -= 2 * dx;
            }

            if (p2 >= 0){
                origin.z += zs;
                p2 -= 2 * dx;
            }
            p1 += 2 * dy;
            p2 += 2 * dz;
            if(getIndex(vec3(origin.x,origin.y,origin.z))==1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (dy >= dx && dy >= dz){
        float p1 = 2 * dx - dy;
        float p2 = 2 * dz - dy;
        while (origin.y != dir.y){
            origin.y += ys;

            if (p1 >= 0){
                origin.x += xs;
                p1 -= 2 * dy;
            }

            if (p2 >= 0){
                origin.z += zs;
                p2 -= 2 * dy;
            }

            p1 += 2 * dx;
            p2 += 2 * dz;
            if(getIndex(vec3(origin.x,origin.y,origin.z))==1){
                return true;
            }
        }


    }

    else{
        float p1 = 2 * dy - dz;
        float p2 = 2 * dx - dz;
        while (origin.z != dir.z){
            origin.z += zs;
            if (p1 >= 0){
                origin.z += ys;
                p1 -= 2 * dz;
            }
            if (p2 >= 0){
                origin.x += xs;
                p2 -= 2 * dz;
            }

            p1 += 2 * dy;
            p2 += 2 * dx;
            if(getIndex(vec3(origin.x,origin.y,origin.z))==1){
                return true;
            }

        }


    }
    return false;

}


void main(){
    vec3 position = cameraPos - vec3(gl_FragCoord.x/1200*2-1,gl_FragCoord.y/900*2-1,1);
    vec3 dir = normalize(position)*100;
    vec3 color = vec3(0,0,0);

    position = vec3(int(position.x),int(position.y),int(position.z));
    dir = vec3(int(dir.x),int(dir.y),int(dir.z));

    if(bresenham(position, dir)){
        color  = vec3(1,1,1);
    }

    fragColor = vec4(color,1);




}
```

I dont get any error number of sorts from the crash. All that happens is a black screen and after the image comes back i get a ".. nvidia drivers stopped responding error".

Comment: The `while` loops seems to be endless loops. A condition like `(origin.x != dir.x)` will (almost) never evaluate to `false`, because `origin.x` and `dir.x` are floating point values. Probably it has to be `origin.x < dir.x`

Comment: @Rabbid76 oh sry i didnt mention that i cast them to int before giving them to the function. I was already thinking that. I also tried with floating points and using the < instead.

Comment: `vec3` is a vector of 3 floats, if you want integers you need `ivec3`.

Comment: im aware of that. but since i cast the values to int the end up as full numbers (1.0,2.0 and so on) anyway and only adding and subtracting full numbers should satisfy the != equation. I tried it both ways however and no change so i dont think this is the problem. What i dont understand is why my artifical while loop that doesnt terminate work? Does opengls compiler detect nonsense in code maybe and optimizes it?

Comment: Just a side note: when i recall right per defaul JOGL is running shaders in Compatibility Profile "#version xxx compatibility" you need to force to "#version xxx core" in order to redeclare gl_FragCoord. And yes, while loop sometimes (in development) a bit tricky, try to use a break statement somewhere. Just few things to try out, so to say.